# In Desktop view screen will be left and right column in mobile view top & bottom using bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In Desktop view screen will be shown as left and right column in mobile view the same screen will be shown as  top & bottom using bootstrap 5

For example in desktop view

---

### A  B

But in mobile View

---

```
B
A
```

---

Here is my code

```
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="img-al">
                <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="images/uiw_login.png">
                <h2 class="img_text">
                   Client Login
                </h2>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Code"><br/>
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <input style="margin-left:45px;" type="checkbox"> I'm not a robot
                <span><img src="images/Vector.png"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button class="lgn_btn">
                    Login
                </button><br/><br/>
                <p style="margin-left:40px;margin-top: 24px;">New here ? <a href="#" style="color: red;">Non - Client SignUp</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="auth" src="images/Two_factor_authentication.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The image is showing correct in desktop

[image]

In Mobile mode

[image]

Actually the image should be in top and login form should be in down

I tried using Push and pull but that is not working

This is the [bootstrap 5.0.2](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20integrity=%22sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E) version I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using order class.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 order-2 order-md-1">
        <div class="img-al">
            <img style="vertical-align: middle;" src="images/uiw_login.png">
            <h2 class="img_text">
               Client Login
            </h2>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client Code"><br/>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <input style="margin-left:45px;" type="checkbox"> I'm not a robot
            <span><img src="images/Vector.png"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="lgn_btn">
                Login
            </button><br/><br/>
            <p style="margin-left:40px;margin-top: 24px;">New here ? <a href="#" style="color: red;">Non - Client SignUp</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 order-1 order-md-2">
        <img class="auth" src="images/Two_factor_authentication.png">
    </div>
</div>
```